# __getitem__ method with tuple argument using Python C-API

Tags: python, python-c-api

Is it possible to define a class with  a `__getitem__` that takes a `tuple` argument using the Python C-API?
The `sq_item` member of the `tp_as_sequence` member of a `PyTypeObject`
must be a `ssizeargfunc`, so I don't see how to do it.
(But I assume that the NumPy `ndarray` does it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `tp_as_mapping` instead.

Its `mp_subscript` takes a `PyObject *` so you can use anything as index/key.

To understand how they relate, you could have a look at the source of `PyObject_GetItem()` which (as the doc says) is the equivalent of Python `o[key]` expression. You will see that it first tries `tp_as_mapping` and if that's not there and key is `int`, it tries `tp_as_sequence`.